# Angular JS 1.3 - Animating Ng-Repeat and Ng-Show Elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have a list of `ng-repeat` items.  Only one of the items are shown at any one time and the rest are hidden using `ng-show`.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="test" ng-repeat="(key, object) in textData" ng-show="index == key">
        {{object}}
    </div>
<div>
```

I cycle through the elements using `$interval`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $interval){

    $scope.index = 1;
    $scope.changeIndex = function(){
        if($scope.index == 3){
            $scope.index = 1;
        }
        else{
            $scope.index = $scope.index + 1;
        }
    };
    $interval($scope.changeIndex, 3000);

    $scope.textData = {
        1: 'one',
        2: 'two',
        3: 'three'
    };

});
```

I would like to animate the transition between the elements with a fade in and fade out effect.  I tried using

```
.test.ng-move{
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    opacity:0;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

How would I achieve this animation effect with Angular 1.3?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fau8orku/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will get quite the affect you are looking for with showing/hiding the elements within, because they will always be in the same order. But to accomplish what you are asking you would need to *target the class that is being added/removed for the fade out*, and the *basic* class for the fade in:

```
.test.ng-hide{
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

.test{
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:1;
}
```

`ng-hide` is added when `ng-show="{{ falsy }}"`. `test` is simply your shown state.

Here is your updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fau8orku/6/). Hopefully this will get you on the right track.